# How to add more planners to ompl_ros_interface?

Tags: ros, motion-planning, arm-navigation, ompl-ros-interface, ompl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am using fuerte arm_navigation pkg and its wizard to build my own robot_arm_navigation pkg.
In ompl_planning.yaml, there are already 2 planners, i.e. SBL and LBKPIECE.

How to add more sampling-based planners* into ompl_planning.yaml?

*) Expansive Space Trees (EST), Rapidly-exploring Random Trees (RRT), Probabilistic RoadMaps (PRM), ...

I guess that it is by adding several lines in planner_configs section, if that is true, then what should I write there e.g. for EST, RRT, PRM, ...?

\update

I have tried to "slightly" modify the ompl_planning.yaml to add RRTConnect planner, but no luck. During launching robot_arm_navigation, I got:

```
TypeError: cannot marshal None unless allow_none is enabled
```

I did add 3 things into ompl_planning.yaml

```
planner_configs:
RRTConnectkConfig1:
type: kinematic::RRTConnect
```

and

```
right_arm:
  planner_configs:
    - RRTConnectkConfig1
```

and

```
right_arm_cartesian:
  planner_configs:
    - RRTConnectkConfig1
```

and, surely, changed the default_planner_config param.

Did I miss something obvious?
Where else should I adjust?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34641/how-to-add-more-planners-to-ompl_ros_interface?/) by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2012-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

You need to create a new planning configuration that has the new planner name.

Open pr2_arm_navigation_planning/config/ompl_planning.yaml
and update to something like this:

```
right_arm:
  planner_type: JointPlanner
  planner_configs:
    - SBLkConfig1 
    - RRTConnectkConfig1
    - LBKPIECEkConfig1
```

Make sure you follow the syntax correctly. The error you have seems to be a parsing one.

Then, you need to define what RRTConnectkConfig1 means. At the bottom of the file, where you have the planner_configs, update to something like this:

```
planner_configs:
  SBLkConfig1:
    type: kinematic::SBL

  RRTConnectkConfig1:
    type: kinematic::RRTConnect

  LBKPIECEkConfig1:
    type: kinematic::LBKPIECE
```

For the list of possible planner types to use see ompl_ros_planning_group.cpp in ompl_interface_ros. I'm sorry for the poor documentation. This will be easier in MoveIt!

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2012-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GuiHome](https://answers.ros.org/users/768/guihome/) on 2012-07-23**:
We are on Electric and would like to use PRM but it seems not to be supported yet. We get "Unknown planner type" and PRM is not into initializePlanner. Is there a reason for this ? Do you think copy/past and adaptation of RRT initialization would work ?

**Comment by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) on 2012-07-24**:
You need to add a new configuration item like I described above.  Add a planner config named for example myPRMConfig under right_arm and then under planner_configs, add
myPRMConfig:
type: kinematic::PRM

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2012-07-24**:
Hmm, but where is the PRM planner initialisation located inside the ompl_ros_interface code? As GuiHome pointed out, there is no initializePRMPlanner() in the ompl_ros_planning_group.h/cpp. Is it hiding somewhere else?